# Use intermediate language in racket to find permutations of a list

Tags: algorithm, list, functional-programming, scheme, racket

I have recently started learning racket and scheme. I am practicing some operations on list and I want to find out all the permutations of a list using recursive strategy. This function will return a list of all possible list of permutations. i.e. (permute '(1 2)) will give (list (list 1 2) (list 2 1)).

Here is my function for that,

```
(define (permute l)
  (cond
    [(empty? l) (cons list(list))]

    [(empty? (rest l)) (list l)]

    [(= (length l) 2)
     (list (cons (second l) (list (first l)))(cons (first l) (list (second l))))
    ]

    [else (????)
    ]

    ))
```

My confusion is that how can I use this function to generate all permutations that has length longer than 2. As I am using Intermediate student language in racket I can't use lambda.

Can anyone help me to understand what to do next?

Comment: I had seen that answer but as I said I can't use lambda. So for that reason I asked this question. @Oscar Lopez

Comment: You're using lambda in your solution, it's implicit in the procedure definition. If that bothers you, simply extract the lambda as a named helper procedure - just understand that you'll _always_ use a lambda in the end, even if it's implicit.

Comment: Okay, got it! Thanks